# sqlite and datetime / strftime formatting issue

Tags: sqlite, strftime

I have a unix timestamp from yesterday ('1384335000 ' = 11-13-2013) that I have saved in the database. I want to format that string into a `mm-dd-yyyy` format but cannot seem to get this just right.

The output of what I am getting back is: 13.11.2013. Even if I use `strftime` and format the stamp, it will never show as I want it to.

Here is my code:

```
datetime( e.start, 'unixepoch', 'localtime' ) AS testdate
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
I've tried using strftime again and I get `13.10.1910` back from this:

```
strftime('%m-%d-%Y', e.start, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS testdate
```

Comment: I believe the unix timestamp is seconds since 1970.

Comment: Yep. Seconds since Jan 1, 1970, UTC time. Create a reference date and add the seconds.

Comment: Thanks Millie. I've got it working now. If you'd like to post that as the answer, I'd be happy to credit you. Thanks again.

Comment: Youre welcome. There you go. Thanks. I'm a C# developer and I'm out right now so I can't post code.

Comment: No problem, Millie. You were very helpful. I'm on the PHP side of things and decided to give SQLite a go for this project. It's making me earn my money for sure.

Comment: I recently took up sqlite for my xamarin project and had problems with dates, as shown by my latest question, so it was fresh in my mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unix timestamp is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC time. Create a reference date and add the seconds to it.

[Unix timestamp wiki](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: quick question. Is what you're describing UTC?